# Is there a way to display an error/reminder message when unlocking a sheet in a workbook?

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out a backup creation solution for one excel based process.
An idea that came to my mind is locking the sheets of the workbook and displaying a reminder message to the users when unlocking the sheets so that they don't forget to print the sheet into a pdf before saving the workbook with their modifications.
An automated pdf print after unlock could also be a solution.
Is there a way to do either or both of these?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VBA, in the `ThisWorkbook` module insert this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not SaveAsUI Then
        If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Printed" Then
            MsgBox ("You haven't printed the book")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

the code: `If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Printed" Then` is just something like a boolean, you can explore more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is a different approach that I had in mind but might be just perfect.
However, it is not clear for me how the "Printed" value gets into ("Sheet1").Range("A2") so that the message box doesn't keep coming up before every save. Can you help with that? Thanks.

Comment: Let assume you jave another code that prints the document, after printing it will put printed in sheet1.rangeA2.